# Python: Create vectors of same length using two DataFrames

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes as follows:

```
d1 = {'person' : ['1', '1', '1', '2', '2', '3', '3', '4', '4'],
     'category' : ['A', 'B', 'C', 'B', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'F', 'D'],
     'value' : [2, 3, 1, 2, 1, 4, 2, 1, 3]}

d2 = {'group' : [100, 100, 100, 200, 200, 300, 300],
     'category' : ['A', 'D', 'F', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'F'],
     'value' : [10, 8, 8, 6, 7, 8, 5]}
```

I want to get vectors of the same length out of the column **category** (i.e. indexed by **category**) for each **person** and **group**. In other words, I want to transform this long dataframes into wide format where the name of the new columns are the values of the column **category**.

What is the best way to do this? This is an example of what I need:

```
     id    type   A  B  C  D  E  F
0   100   group  10  0  0  8  0  8
1   200   group   0  6  7  0  0  0
2   300   group   8  0  0  0  0  5
3     1  person   2  3  1  0  0  0
4     2  person   0  2  0  1  0  0
5     3  person   0  0  0  0  4  2
6     4  person   0  0  0  3  0  1
```

My current script appends both dataframes and then it gets a pivot table. My concern is that in this case the types of the **id** columns are different.

I do this because sometimes not all the categories are in each dataframe (e.g. 'E' is not in df2).

This is what I have:

```
import pandas as pd

d1 = {'person' : ['1', '1', '1', '2', '2', '3', '3', '4', '4'],
     'category' : ['A', 'B', 'C', 'B', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'F', 'D'],
     'value' : [2, 3, 1, 2, 1, 4, 2, 1, 3]}

d2 = {'group' : [100, 100, 100, 200, 200, 300, 300],
     'category' : ['A', 'D', 'F', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'F'],
     'value' : [10, 8, 8, 6, 7, 8, 5]}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(d1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(d2)

df1['type'] = 'person'
df2['type'] = 'group'

df1.rename(columns={'person': 'id'}, inplace = True)
df2.rename(columns={'group': 'id'}, inplace = True)

rawpivot = pd.DataFrame([])
rawpivot = rawpivot.append(df1)
rawpivot = rawpivot.append(df2)

pivot = rawpivot.pivot_table(index=['id','type'], columns='category', values='value', aggfunc='sum', fill_value=0)
pivot.reset_index(inplace = True)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

d1 = {'person' : ['1', '1', '1', '2', '2', '3', '3', '4', '4'],
     'category' : ['A', 'B', 'C', 'B', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'F', 'D'],
     'value' : [2, 3, 1, 2, 1, 4, 2, 1, 3]}

d2 = {'group' : [100, 100, 100, 200, 200, 300, 300],
     'category' : ['A', 'D', 'F', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'F'],
     'value' : [10, 8, 8, 6, 7, 8, 5]}

cols = ['idx', 'type', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F']
df1 = pd.DataFrame(columns=cols)

def add_data(type_, data):
    global df1
    for id_, category, value in zip(data[type_], data['category'], data['value']):
        if id_ not in df1.idx.values:
            row = pd.DataFrame({'idx': id_, 'type': type_}, columns = cols, index=[0])
            df1 = df1.append(row, ignore_index = True)
        df1.loc[df1['idx']==id_, category] = value

add_data('group', d2)
add_data('person', d1)
df1 = df1.fillna(0)
```

`df1` now holds the following values

```
   idx    type   A  B  C  D  E  F
0  100   group  10  0  0  8  0  8
1  200   group   0  6  7  0  0  0
2  300   group   8  0  0  0  0  5
3    1  person   2  3  1  0  0  0
4    2  person   0  2  0  1  0  0
5    3  person   0  0  0  0  4  2
6    4  person   0  0  0  3  0  1
```